# Why is this error cropping up : can't provide secure connection

Tags: javascript, express

my pug code

```
each question in questions
      section#ques
        .card.w-75
          .card-body
            h5.card-title By !{ question.name }
            p.card-text !{ question.question }
            a.btn.btn-primary(class='View' href=`https://localhost:8080/show/?id=${question.id}`) View
            |
            |
            a.btn.btn-primary(class='ans' href=`https://localhost:8080/answer/?id=${question.id}`) Answer
```

my js code

```
app.get('/show/:id', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.query.id);
    db.find({ id: req.query.id }, (err, results) => {
        console.log(results[0]);
        res.render('view', { question: results[0].question, answers: results[0].answers, name: results[0].name });
    });

});
```

this is app is using express js, nedb, pug
Clicking the button is causing problems and errors. could you please help ? i am in a hurry

Comment: Because you're probably listening on HTTP on localhost, but you're calling HTTPS. For that matter you don't need the full URL, you need only `href="/show/?id=..."`

Comment: no i did app.listen(8080); at the end. Does this listen for HTTP, @JeremyThille ?

Comment: I don't know. Did you import the http or https module?

Comment: @JeremyThille I didn't import either of them. Should I do that ? This app code is on github.com (not the code in OP as it did not run and I had a competition ). Link : https://github.com/skaadin/ras